# How to track the deletion of Task Comments (e.g. //TODO) from a .cs file

Tags: c#, events, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins

Is there any built-in event to catch the removal of a Task Comment by the user?

Currently, we develop a Visual Studio AddIn and we have to react on the creation and deletion of Task Comments (e.g. //TODO or //HACK). The `EnvDTE.TaskListEvents.TaskAdded` event provides us with the possibility to catch newly created or modified Task Comments.

We are aware of the `EnvDTE.TaskListEvents.TaskRemoved` event, but it is never fired if a Task Comment like `//TODO` is removed from the document by the user. Apparently, this event only indicates the deletion of User Tasks where as `TaskAdded` is fired for both, User Tasks and Task Comments. How do we react on the deletion of Task Comments then?

Our AddIn highly depends on tracking `//TODOs` and every hint is highly appreciated.